# Return only last record after ordering records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called racing with the fields ID, race, started, and position. I am trying to figure out the best approach to return only the latest position for that user and that race where the race has not started (race="N").

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from racing order by position where race =
$the_race and 'started' = "N");
```

This would return all races that haven't started and put them in order by "position".
However, after I get the positions in order, I only want to return the LAST position. I can't find info on which method to use for this...

Comment: You mean like the position on grid? And *this* would do nothing of the kind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from racing  where race =
$the_race and started = 'N' order by position desc limit 1");
```

Comment: That was it. I couldn't pull it. Thanks. Will approve answer in moment